# Vlookup Excel Vba Dynamic Values

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

i am trying to create a dynamic vlookup with vba 
please find below my code and tell me what is wrong, it keeps giving #VALUE error

```
Sub ADO_Conn()
Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset
Dim mee As String
Dim Rangerr As Variant
LASTIDX = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox LASTIDX
    For i = 2 To LASTIDX
    mee = Range("G" & i)

    Rangerr = ['C:\Users\ssalako\Documents\[xpress work 12.xlsx]xpr7thmarch'!$J:$P]

   Cells(i, 8).Value = Application.VLookup(mee, Rangerr, 2, 0)
Next i
         MsgBox "DATA LOADED"
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use Evaluate (which is what the `[]` notation effectively is) with a closed workbook. Put a formula into the cell, then convert it to a value.

Comment: i was having errors with passing the path to the vlookup argument, do you know of any other way i can achieve this

Comment: You'd need to use something like: `Cells(i, 8).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(G" & i &  ",'C:\Users\ssalako\Documents\[xpress work 12.xlsx]xpr7thmarch'!$J:$P,2,false)"`

Comment: i know how to put that string, but i have different files with the same columns and want to pass them at different intervals, but the file names change, how do you suggest i do that

Comment: Just amend the formula string.